# Why is CoD: MW2's performance poor running under Low settings?

Tags: performance, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I am playing *Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2* in 'Low' settings, I have a Core2Duo processor clocked at 2.8 GHz, 2GB RAM, an nVidia GT 218 Ion PCI x1 slot 512mb 64 bit GPU. Its more than the games minimum requirements, my drivers are all up to date and I'm still experiencing lag.

Why is this so? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: How you even have a 64 bit operating system running on 2GB of RAM amazes me.

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU seams to be the bottleneck.
[Unfortunately you don't meet the minimum requirements:](http://gamesystemrequirements.com/game/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2)

- **CPU**: Intel Pentium 4 3.2 GHz or AMD Athlon 64 3200+ processor or better supported
- **RAM**: 1 GB RAM
- **GPU**: 256 MB NVIDIA GeForce 6600GT or better or ATI Radeon 1600XT or better (Shader 3.0)

Comment: Core2Duo is a newer processor than the Intel Pentium 4, and is MUCH faster.